# How can I implement REST and secured connection (certificates) over NIO ServerSocketChannel

Tags: java, rest, chat, nio

I would like to create a chat application.
On the server side I would like to use NIO channels and selectors for the incomming connections (because it doesn't consume much memory like threading per connection).

Questions:
1. How can I implement REST (like JAX-RS) over NIO server sockets?
2. How can I implement secure connections over NIO?
Are there any libraries that already do this?

I know chats are usually implemented with simple TCP, but I want this one to handle REST calls rather than permanent TCP connections.

Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI this is one of the primary purposes web sockets was developed for. And there is an API for web sockets in Java EE

Comment: You can use this library https://github.com/tix320/sonder. It works on selector and provide RPC communication.